# Create mixed case table name/columns in oracle WITHOUT using quotes

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way I can create a mixed case table name in Oracle without using quotes?

The table names change to uppercase if I do not use quotes while creating the table.

Let me know if you need more information.

Eg:

```
create table testTable(testColumn varchar);
```

This creates a table named TESTTABLE with column name TESTCOLUMN.

I can use quotes, but it makes it more messy and difficult to write queries.

Can you please let me know how I can do this without using quotes? Thanks.

Regards,
Sawan

Comment: You can just write the table name without quotes and then refer to it as `testTable`.  Be case-insensitive!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but is there a way I can display the names as mixed case in SQL developer without using quotes?

Comment: No.  Oracle treats case sensitivity differently that SQL Server.  In the oracle world, instead of mixed case for clarity, we use underscores.  So, Instead of 'testTable', we'd  use 'test_table'.  Always without quotes, so that it is effectively case-insensitive.      If I were working in SQL Server, I'd probably use mixed-case. Not because I have any preference for it, but because that is how things work there.   When in Rome ... take off your MS goggles.

Comment: Thank you. This helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the official Oracle Database documentation:

"Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them as uppercase."

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49

All the data dictionary views will show the identifiers as Oracle interprets them. In other words, without quotes everything will be uppercase. I can testify that this is true even for accented characters.

You can't always get what you want...